# Sonarqube coverage 0% in react js

Tags: sonarqube, jestjs, sonarscanner

I have written some unit tests in jest. All of them are successful. Able to view test coverage report generated by jest[image]

But my sonarqube dashboard always shows 0% on coverage but unit tests are being detected.

[image]

I am using **jest-sonar-reporter** for sonar consumable format generation of reports.

This is my sonar properties file

```
sonar.projectKey=skyflow-app
sonar.projectName=Skyflow App
sonar.host.url = http://localhost:9000
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=src
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**,**/*.spec.ts, **/*.stories.tsx
sonar.tests=src
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.test.tsx,**/*.test.ts
sonar.test.exclusions=**/*.stories.tsx
sonar.ts.tslintconfigpath=tslint.json
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=testResults/sonar-report.xml
# sonar.coverageReportPaths = coverage/lcov.info
sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths = coverage/lcov.info
```

Please let me know where i am going wrong.

Comment: did you define `sonar.language=js` and `sonar.profile=`

Comment: and what's output error when you build ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A dumb mistake from myside.

Replacing `sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths` with 
`sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths` solved the issue.

Comment: The docs say you can use `sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths` for both js and ts. https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/

Comment: As of this year (2023) `sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths` has been deprecated

Answer (score -1):

can you share console output of the jenkins job?

in my case, jenkins cannot find the coverage report and got log in console output like this :

```
15:26:37  [ERROR] Coverage report '/home/jenkins/workspace/microservices-pipelines/xxx/target/jacoco.exec' could not be read/imported. Error: {}
15:26:37  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to parse JaCoCo XML report: /home/jenkins/workspace/microservices-pipelines/xxx/target/jacoco.exec
```

Comment: Same here, Did you able to fix this? Please provide suggestion if you have fixed.

Thanks in advance